# A mutual constraint for multiple curve fit sessions

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I have `N` sequences of 2D data `(x,y)` I'm trying to fit into a model of a logistic function `y(x)=L/(1+a exp(b*(x-c)))`. However I  would like to put constraints on `a,b,c`. Normally if I want to restrain their values I use the parameters from `lmfit` and it does the job. This time I would like that the ratio of `a/b` would be constant (with an error of 0.01). Is there any way to fit all `N` sequences so the difference between the ratios `a_i/b_i` would be minimized?

Comment: just replace `a` by `b * alpha * ( 1 + 0.01 * 2 / pi * arctan( delta ) )` where `alpha` is your desired constant and `delta` fits for the allowed error.

Comment: I have already tried such thing but the computer cannot find such `alpha` that easily.

Comment: Well, does a single fit sanity check with `a` and `b` suggest that there is a reasonable `alpha` in the first place?

Comment: Tried with the first 3 sequences. `alpha1=10^-4,alpha2=10^-8,alpha3=5` so right now there is a high variance between them. @mikuszefski

Comment: Hmm, looks like the model is not really valid then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear whether you mean that `a_i/b_i` should be the same constant for all N datasets -- let's assume that it should be.
In such a case, it may be sufficient to define parameters like this:

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Parameters, Model

def logistic(x, amp, a, b, c):
    return amp / (1 + a*np.exp(b*(x-c)))
 
params = Parameters()
params.add('b2a_scale' value=1, vary=True) # ?
N = 5
model = Model(logistic, prefix='p1_')

for i in range(1, N+1):
    params.add('p%d_amp' % i, value=1, min=0)
    params.add('p%d_c' % i, value=1)
    params.add('p%d_b' % i, value=5)
    params.add('p%d_a' % i, expr='p%d_b * b2a_scale' % i)
    if model > 1:
        model += Model(logistic, prefix='p%d_' % i)
```